# How to determine that only visible images downloaded complete and render in page

Tags: jquery

here is code by which i can implement image lazyload functionality. i need to know when only visible images downloaded complete and render in page. how it will be possible.

### here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("table[id*=dgImages] img").each(function () {
if($(this).offset().top > $(window).scrollTop() && $(this).offset().top <    $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {

  // callback on load complete          
  this.onload = function() { 
    alert('this image download complete'); 
    $(this).fadeIn('slow');
  }

  $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("original"));
  $(this).removeAttr("original");
}
});
});
```

with the help of the below code i can make sure when each image download complete at client side.

```
this.onload = function() { 
    alert('this image download complete'); 
    $(this).fadeIn('slow');
  }
```

so i need another callback mechanism which fire and notify me that only visible images downloaded complete and render in page. please discuss this issue how to achieve it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe [`this one`](https://github.com/galaxycats/load-visible-images) helps u

Comment: it is good but i am looking for different solution. i want to know what code i need to add in my existing code by which can determine when all visible images download complete.....if u have any idea then plzz share with me just modifying my code. thanks.

Comment: you can see the logic in there. I just refer to see the logic not to use this :)

Comment: i saw that logic bit there. there is logic to determine when each image download complete. i need a logic which fire when all visible images download complete. thanks